# Python socket.close() does not work until the script exit

Tags: python, sockets, client, ironpython

Client Codes:

```
fwd = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
fwd.connect((oriIp,oriPort)
fwd.close()
```

I found the close() function did not work.
My server (c#) shows the connection still alive.
Until the python script is closed , the server will show the state of connection is closed.

I use IronPython 2.7.

Comment: How do you check the status of the connection in the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See python docs for socket:

> Note: close() releases the resource associated with a connection but
>   does not 
>       necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the 
>       connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close().

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Comment: Yea, I find it. And it is still confused me why the composer designed it like this style. On the other way, it seems if I call close() lonely , the connection will keep for a long time. How long time will it keep? Thanks

Comment: @NorSDNorSD Looking at the Python source for v2.7.3, the `close` method is just a call to the C `close` method, so if you want more information you should check the behaviour of `close` on socket descriptor. I found this http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-a-Socket.html, explaining that `close` will send any remaining data before trying to close the socket, so the "timeout" maybe hard to predict.